# setimage alapha not working in android 5.1

Tags: java, android

I am runing simple android application/java for android 5.1
the transparency change is not working for me . Can you advise 
code below , Thanks a lot

```
 @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            txtInput1 = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.txtInput1);
            btnSubmit = (Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSubmit);
            imageMyCat = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageMyCat);
        }

        public void onClick(View view)
        {
            String trans1 = txtInput1.getText().toString();
            if (!"".equals(trans1))
            {
                int transparency1 = Integer.parseInt(trans1);
                if (transparency1 < 0 || transparency1 > 100)
                    txtInput1.setError("range is 0-100");
                else
                    imageMyCat.setAlpha(transparency1/100f);
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use `setImageAlpha(int)` to change opacity of image. It accepts value in range of `0 - 255`

`public void setImageAlpha (int alpha)`

Sets the alpha value that should be applied to the image.

> Parameters - alpha (`int`): the alpha value that should be applied to the
>   image (between 0 and 255 inclusive, with 0 being transparent and 255
>   being opaque)

Check documentation here https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView#setImageAlpha(int)

Answer (score 0):

You can put `android:alpha` in your `ImageView` `XML` tag: use value from 0.1 to 1.0

`<ImageView android:alpha="0.4">`